# Installing Disastry's PGP 2.6.3ia multi06 on 12.04 LTS

Tags: pgp

How can I install Disastry's version of PGP 2.6.3ia-multi06 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

His site with the source code is here:
http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/disastry/263multi.htm

He already compiled a unix version of pgp and it's in the Linux section of his download.

How can I either copy and install the binary PGP file, or compile it from the source and install.

I have tried several different ways, get no error messages, but when I type  pgp -h at the command line, Ubuntu tells me that pgp is not installed.

(I already have truecrypt 7.1a and gnupg 1.4.16 installed, but still like the old pgp I have on windows)

Thanks!

traveler

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put it somewhere in your `$PATH`. A common place would be `/usr/local/bin`, which is for software installed on your own (but make sure the folder actually is in your `$PATH` variable, or add it).

If you just want to see if the very outdated binary is still able to run in your system, execute it by typing the path to it (or running `./pgp` if it is in your working directory).

Pretty much the same applies if you compiled it on your own, but expect serious dependency problems with software created for 11+ years old environments.

---

Anyway: Are you sure you want to use security-critical software that wasn't updated for 11 years from some more or less random site on the internet? Furthermore, it inclines severe compatibility issues, and never heard of RFC4880 in use today, and the next update is already in queue... You even cannot read pretty much all recent OpenPGP (v4) keys.

Comment: Knew the developer personally before he died in a mountain climbing accident. I trust his key and anything signed with it, including the binaries.  It is an updated version of PGP 2.x, and can read all current rfc4880 hashes and algorithms except Camelia, and is compatible with GnuPG as long as v3 keys are used, or conventional encryption is used.

Comment: I need it on Ubuntu because I use it as an signed encrypted 'uuencode' substitute that allows sending any file or program as email text and splitting it up and reconstituting it. Thanks for helping make it happen!!